# Wordpress - How to add advanced TinyMCE WYSIWYG editor to a textarea box in custom page, not meta box

Tags: wordpress, tinymce

I have a custom page, php code. 
I have a regular textarea which is not meta box.
I would like to add the TinyMCE editor to  in the textarea box. 
I install the Advanced TinyMCE, but I did not know how to add it so it will be shown in the textarea.
I did not see the TinyMCE also it the regular Wordpress post.

Is there a simple tutorial that explain it?

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

The function you are looking for is wp_editor(). For more information you should refer to the [documentation](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/wp_editor/).

Comment: Please read more about asking a good question on Stack overflow profile. You can read this article for better understanding and asking a good question: https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask